# Does "Recommend deletion" also down vote?

Tags: support, review-queues, downvotes, low-quality-posts

In the LQP queue I selected "Recommend deletion" to a link only answer. I promptly got a "why down vote?" comment from the OP.

Does "Recommend deletion" automatically down vote or was there a coincidental second down voter? Not a problem if it does auto down vote, seems reasonable, but I would just like to know.

Comment: The downvote could have been cast a while ago. You got the "why?" comment because your comment from the review generated a notification for the author, who went to look at the post and saw the negative score. Their comment wasn't necessarily even addressed to you; "why the downvote?" is often written to nobody in particular, but you are notified if nobody else commented on the post.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it does not cast a downvote.

It's not particularly coincidental though, the person that flagged the post in the first place to put it into the queue likely downvoted.